# PHP storing array as a dictionary, how to get the key and the value?

Tags: php, arrays

This seems simple enough, but my googling seems to be off to get the right answer:

I am dynamically making an array

```
$data = array();

$data['this is text'] = 1312;
$data['heres more text'] = 191;
$data['im also a unique entry'] = 239
```

I then want to go through each item and get the key and the value:

```
foreach($data as $datapoint)
{   
    var_dump($datapoint); //this seems to just be the value
    $k = key($garavg); //this does not work because datapoint is a value not an array
}
```

I simply want to be able to do this:

```
echo "$key has this many entries $value";
```

Comment: See the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php (Hint: It's `foreach ($data as $key => $value)`).

Comment: you need to learn how to use Google better. This is purely basics.

Comment: In case it helps for future googling, "dictionaries" are typically called _associative arrays_ in php.

Comment: Acutally, `key` is a typo in your question as that is treated as a constant (even a function), rather than the intended `$key` variable. Plus, syntatically speaking; you're missing a semi-colon here `$data['im also a unique entry'] = 239`. *Just saying*, unless it's just a bad paste.

Answer (score 2):

`foreach` has that built in:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value )
{   
    echo "$key has this many entries $value";
}
```